# How to use AddressChooserTask to get user address detail

Tags: windows-phone-7, android-asynctask

I have an class which use AddressChooserTask to show user address. I want to fetch user city, country and region detail from that How can i do that my AddressChooserTask.Completed event is:

```
void AddressChooserTask_Completed(object sender, AddressResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult==TaskResult.OK)
    {
            // Fetch the selected Contact Address
            MessageBox.Show(e.Address);
    }
}
```

Result: Lumkard park, near ICICI Bank, Pune Maharashtra 422195 india

i want to store city, country, pincode in seperate variable any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance